# Spring Boot 2.1 + Spring Web Flow

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflow-2

I am trying to get the Spring Web Flow to work with the latest Spring Boot 2.1.0 but they don’t seem to play well together due to dependency version incompatibility, and there isn’t an official spring boot starter for SWF. Has anyone encountered this and has a solution or some suggestions?

I get this error on startup:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call the method org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinition.setRole(I)V but it does not exist. Its class, org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinition, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/Users/lorenzo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.0.9.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/AnnotatedBeanDefinition.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/Users/lorenzo/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.0.9.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar
```

Output of Maven's dependencies tree below

```
mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.springframework:spring-beans



[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ clayton ---
[INFO] io.clayton:clayton:jar:5.0.0
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.0.9.RELEASE)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:jar:2.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security.oauth:spring-security-oauth2:jar:2.3.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.0.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.1.3.RELEASE)
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client:jar:2.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:5.1.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.1.3.RELEASE:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO] \- org.springframework.webflow:spring-webflow:jar:2.5.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.webflow:spring-binding:jar:2.5.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  \- (org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile - omitted for conflict with 5.1.3.RELEASE)
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.0.9.RELEASE:compile
```

POM

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>


    <!-- Repositories ============================================= -->
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.spring.release</id>
            <name>Spring GA Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jgit-repository</id>
            <url>https://repo.eclipse.org/content/groups/releases/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-boot>2.1.1.RELEASE</spring-boot>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <liquibase.version>3.6.1</liquibase.version>
        <antlr-version>4.7.1</antlr-version>
        <aws-version>1.11.457</aws-version>
        <httpclient-version>4.5.5</httpclient-version>
        <force-version>44.0.0</force-version>
        <wro4j-version>1.8.0</wro4j-version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>

        <!-- Git, GitHub & Co. ============================================= -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jgit</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.jgit</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.3.201810200350-r</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- WebJars ============================================= -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>Semantic-UI</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>angular</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>angular-route</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>angular-sanitize</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>chartjs</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars.bower</groupId>
            <artifactId>momentjs</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Boot ============================================= -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-json</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-test-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Web Flow =============================================== -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- WRO4J =============================================== -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wro4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${wro4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wro4j-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>${wro4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Analysis ============================================= -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>${antlr-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr4</artifactId>
            <version>${antlr-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- HTTP Client & integrations ================================ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${httpclient-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient-cache</artifactId>
            <version>${httpclient-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.stripe</groupId>
            <artifactId>stripe-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.53.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
            <version>${aws-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-sqs</artifactId>
            <version>${aws-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-autoscaling</artifactId>
            <version>${aws-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.force.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>force-wsc</artifactId>
            <version>${force-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.force.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>force-metadata-api</artifactId>
            <version>${force-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Serialization & Export =================================== -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.simpleframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>simple-xml</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.supercsv</groupId>
            <artifactId>super-csv</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Persistence ============================================= -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- UI/View Layer ============================================= -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.pegdown</groupId>
            <artifactId>pegdown</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- Java Essentials ============================================= -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <version>3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.ocpsoft.prettytime</groupId>
            <artifactId>prettytime</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
            <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you share some more information about the dependency version incompatibilities?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I have just managed to add all the details, including runtime error and dependency tree output. Any ideas?

Comment: You have a mixture of Spring Framework 5.0.3 and 5.1.1 on the class path which I suspect means that you are not using Spring Boot's dependency management. Can you share your `pom.xml`?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson all updated with the latest GA versions - same problem applies, pom added

Comment: I have revised the Pom structure to use spring-boot-parent, reusing those dependency versions as much as possibile and I managed to get it running! I’ll close this!